# How to convert the column values of pandas series to list in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, series

I have a pandas series which after printing looks like -

```
0        NaN
1     20.307
2    -16.879
3      4.598
4     21.978
5    -12.913
dtype: float64
```

I would like to convert the values in the second column to a list such that it looks like -

```
[0, 20.307, -16.879, 4.598, 21.978, -12.913]
```

I tried doing - `my_series.iloc[:, 1]` but i am getting the error -
`pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Too many indexers`
Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this nice [overview for pandas indexing](https://www.shanelynn.ie/select-pandas-dataframe-rows-and-columns-using-iloc-loc-and-ix/) to avoid the IndexingError

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If use `iloc[:, 1]` it want select second column, but in `Series` is no columns, so raise error.

If want select all values without first use indexing `[1:]`:

```
L = my_series.iloc[1:].tolist()
```

Or remove missing values by [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html):

```
L = my_series.dropna().tolist()
```

Or replace `NaN` to `0` by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
L = my_series.fillna(0).tolist()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Series.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
In [2640]: my_series.fillna(0).tolist()
Out[2640]: [0.0, 20.307, -16.879, 4.598, 21.978, -12.913]
```

Comment: When I answered your answer had first two parts. Hence I answered with `fillna()`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try

```
list(df.my_series.fillna(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see from your expected result, you don't want to
just drop *NaN* elements but rather to convert them
to *0*.

So to get your desired result, run:

```
result = my_series.fillna(0).tolist()
```